# Sony Alpha a6000 Charging and battery life for timelapse?

Tags: timelapse, sony-alpha, battery-drain

I am considering buying a Sony Alpha a6000. One of the things I like to do is time-lapse, rather long ones, often several thousand pictures long. The specs of the camera say about 300 pics per battery, and one guy claimed to be getting about a thousand. Since I don't have the camera yet I am unclear about a couple of things I may be able to do to get the pics I need.

Can I turn off the lCD screen while shooting?

I understand the camera has in camera charging, can I plug the camera in to a car charger while shooting, and will this be enough to keep up with the cameras discharge? (I did time-lapse on a cell phone (Lumia) that even when plugged in to the car charger it still discharged)

This question is a [duplicate](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67642/sony-alpha-7-battery-for-timelapse), which was posted about a year ago and received no answers, hopefully someone is now around whom can answer this.

Comment: Doing extended time lapse with a mirrorless camera is not an ideal solution. The reason being that the sensor stays continually energized. The heat buildup can be a significant factor in image quality. I can also cause the camera to shut down for thermal protection.

Comment: This is not a problem with conventional digital cameras like a Canon EOS Rebel for example?

Comment: No, because with DSLRs the sensor isn't energized between exposures since the optical viewfinder doesn't require a signal from the sensor for composition, AF, or metering.

Comment: @MichaelClark Thank you very much, I think the A600 is off my short list.

Comment: Well, shutter durability is also an issue with DSLRs for long timelapses. There's no free lunch. Some mirrorless cameras have a time lapse mode that puts the sensor to "sleep" between shots.

Comment: You can buy an intervalometer app for the a6000 from Sony. I'm not sure if it turns off the sensor between shots.

Comment: There's a lot of good info here: http://www.learntimelapse.com/time-lapse-photography-how-to-guide/

Answer (score 2):

With A6000 can get longer battery life by making selection EVF-LCD manual. This is one of main consumers even the camera is switched off. You can set it to EVF and get more than 350 shoots

Also you can consider making focus manual, again to minimize energy consuming.
And you can switch off prefocus (even if you are on manual focus) to save small amount of energy.

Unfortunately you can't on the same time charge the camera and operate it. To have camera charged via USB you need to switch it off. When you switch it on it stop charging.

P.S. For powering the camera you can consider using some battery adapter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003OBUJD0) or [this](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1241264-REG/tether_tools_case_relay_camera_power.html) (never used and have no affiliate). Also you can check [this](http://briansmith.com/sony-a6300-a6000-camera-accessories-guide/) article about some other options

Answer (score 0):

Sony makes a plug-in AC adapter that will probably give you the power you need. I have not bought it or used it but it should work. I have an a6000.

Answer (score -1):

Sony a6000 is not good for time lapse. It does not have option to turn off the shutter sound and it may damage the hardware if shot even for a couple of thousand shots

Comment: What does the shutter sound have to do with putting together a time lapse? Do you have a source or evidence that this camera won't last even a few thousand shots? Fairly certain that, since released in 2014, more than a few have gone well past a few thousand shots.